# Is it possible to make different Firebase Database for Release and Debug mode in a single project/app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here we are working on the project that uses the Firebase Realtime Database. Is it possible to make different Firebase Database for **Release** and **Debug** mode in single Android app?

Project:(App with release/debug mode)

1. Debug Mode(Test Environment) - Firebase Database 1
2. Release Mode(Production Environment) - Firebase Database 2

What is the best idea to solve this Test/Production environment for Firebase Database?

Answer (score 3):

There is only a single database in a project at the moment. So either you'll need to model debug and release data into the same database or you'll need a separate project for each.

Many of these scenarios are covered in this blog post: [Organizing your Firebase-enabled Android app builds](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `google-services.json` to drive initialisation of Firebase (assuming that's what you're currently doing?), I'd suggest dynamically creating `FirebaseApp` using something like following

```
    String apiKey;
    String databaseUrl;

    if (useDebugDatabase) {
        apiKey = "xxxxxx";
        databaseUrl = "<debug firebase database url>";
    } else {
        apiKey = "xxxxxx"
        databaseUrl = "<release firebase database url>";
    }


    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey(apiKey)
            .setApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.google_app_id))
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, firebaseOptions, "MyApp");

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate databases under the same project and use them for your debug and release builds.

[image]

In the code, just point get instances for different databases based on which build it is.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //Url of new database
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://app-1234.firebaseio.com/");
} else {
    //For release builds use the default database
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}
```